# Flutter how to filter array by condition

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data like this

```
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",
          
            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "score": 100,
                "cost": 0,
                "penalties": []
            },

        },
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",
          
            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "score": 100,
                "penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Speeding",

                    }
                 ]
            },

        },
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",
          
            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Breaking",

                    },
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Speeding",

                    }
                 ]
            },

        },
]
```

I need to filter this array only to show that array which has penalties name Speeding. and print that array.

I am doing something like this

```
  List itemList = data['items'];
  for (Map item in itemList) {
    Map rating = item['rating'];
    if (rating['penalties'] != null) {
      List penalties = rating['penalties'];
      for (Map penalty in penalties) {
        if (penalty['name'] == "Speeding") {
          print(penalties);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but it's showing this error  `Tried calling: []("penalties")` i try to add a condition if not equal to null then print but don't know why it's showing an error.

More Explanation:  I just print the array in which the penalty name is Speeding.\

My function looks like this

```
  getImi() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String imi = await storage.read(key: "imei");

print('showimi');
var url =
    'http://api';
print(url);
http.Response res = await http.get(
  url,
  headers: <String, String>{'token': 'sasasa'},
);
var data = json.decode(res.body.toString());
print(data);

if (data['status'].toString() == "success") {
  Navigator.pop(context);

  var data2 = data;
  var list = data2['items'] as List;

  print(list);
  var match = list
      .where((m) =>
          m['rating']['penalties'] != null &&
          (m['rating']['penalties'] as List)
              .any((sm) => sm['name'] == 'Speeding'))
      .toList();

  print(match);
  setState(() {});
  _shoW = true;
} else {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  _shoW = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run your API all the above methods will run but there is one issue in your data sometimes rating is null and you have to add validation or if conditions on penalties so that the issue you also need to check your rating is null or not.

code will simply look like this and I test it

```
  List itemList = data['items'];

  for (Map item in itemList) {
    Map rating = item['rating'];

    if (rating != null) {
      if (rating['penalties']?.length > 0) {
        print('sss');
        List penalties = rating['penalties'];
        for (Map penalty in penalties) {
          if (penalty['name'] == widget.category) {
            print(item);
            dataa['Items'].add(item);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The most important thing hide your API from the question look like its have some data which must be not shareable.

Answer (score 0):

`List` in dart has a `.where()` method.

```dart
var myList = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 7];
myList.where((item) => item > 5).toList();   // [6, 8, 7]
myList.firstWhere((item) => item > 5);       // 6
myList.lastWhere((item) => item > 5);        // 7
```

Comment: But I am using for loop and by loop, I am adding values in an array. It's working but when penalties are null it's showing an error I have tried to add condition if != null then add but my condition isn't working

Comment: There are a few changes I would recommend on your code. I would probably make a class instead of using multiple levels of maps. Regardless, you can still use the `.where()` method. For example `.where((item) => item['penalties']?.length > 0)` (apologies if I have typos in the code, but you get the gist of the approach)

Comment: BTW, if your code is not strongly typed you will have to convert item['penalties'] into a list for it to have the `length` property. For example `List<dynamic>.from(item['penalties'])`

Answer (score 0):

First, your sample data has commas raising errors when formatting it as JSON, you should delete them.

Second, this works:

*Data file*:

```
const items = '''
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",

            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "score": 100,
                "cost": 0,
                "penalties": []
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",

            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "score": 100,
                "penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Speeding"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782",

            "rating": {
                "profile": "aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb",
                "penalties": [
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Breaking"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c",
                        "name": "Speeding"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
''';
```

*Main file*:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:_samples2/data/data3.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  var data = jsonDecode(items) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  var list = data['items'] as List;
  var match = list.where((m) => m['rating']['penalties'] != null && (m['rating']['penalties'] as List).any((sm) => sm['name'] == 'Speeding')).toList();

  print(match);
}
```

Result:

```
[{id: c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782, rating: {profile: aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb, score: 100, penalties: [{id: acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c, name: Speeding}]}}, {id: c9782d44-8aeb-4a07-8ca5-0c1070841782, rating: {profile: aa99d965-ba5b-4471-bf65-d0a51d8102cb, penalties: [{id: acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c, name: Breaking}, {id: acff7359-51f6-46db-a76c-7d5a899e3f7c, name: Speeding}]}}]
```

Comment: its showing this error Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: try your code like this       var list = itemList;
      var match = list
          .where((m) =>
              m['rating']['penalties'] != null &&
              (m['rating']['penalties'] as List)
                  .any((sm) => sm['name'] == 'Speeding'))
          .toList();  But then its showing same error  The method '[]' was called on null.

Comment: I've added the formatted data used, try with it... coded modified

Comment: I tried I am calling data from API don't know why it's showing a null error on my code. I have added my Api code also can you please check please

Comment: Bro, first you need to verify if your request is working or giving the wished response. I tried it with postman and I get one response about wrong parameters. The request on postman was: `curl "http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/drive_api/trip_show.php\?imei\=358480081983837" -H "token: c66026133e80d4960f0a5b7d418a4d08"`

Comment: First two lines: `Notice: Undefined index: imei in D:\xampp\htdocs\drive_api\trip_show.php on line 7` and `Notice: Undefined variable: asset in D:\xampp\htdocs\drive_api\trip_show.php on line 42`

Comment: Final line: `Warning: array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\drive_api\trip_show.php on line 199
{ "status": "success", "items": null }%`